# Image (literally) runs away from div

Tags: html, css

The yellow dot "gif1" has to go inside the black box "gif" but as you can see I somehow managed to did the opposite.

How many things did I do wrong?

[Livewave Preview](https://liveweave.com/dz5uY7)

I already tried `overflow:auto` or `hidden` and changing the `position` attributes from `relative` to `absolute` and vice versa.

```html
<html>

<head>

  <body>
    <center>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="img_sx"></div>
        <div class="img_dx"></div>
        <div class="quote"></div>
        <div class="gif"><img class="gif1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Scandal_-_Yellow_album_cover.jpg"></div>
        <div class="burp"></div>
        <div class="prot"></div>
      </div>
    </center>

    <style>
      .container {
        width: 550px;
        height: 430px;
        background-color: burlywood;
        display: table;
      }
      
      .img_sx {
        width: 250px;
        height: 430px;
        background-color: cadetblue;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      
      .img_dx {
        width: 210px;
        height: 390px;
        background-color: cornflowerblue;
        margin-left: 250px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
      }
      
      .quote {
        width: 230px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: coral;
        margin-left: 250px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        position: relative;
      }
      
      .gif {
        width: 230px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: black;
        margin-left: 250px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        position: relative;
      }
      
      .gif1 {
        width: 90px;
        border-radius: 90px;
      }
      
      .gif2 {}
      
      .burp {
        width: 230px;
        height: 90px;
        background-color: white;
        margin-left: 250px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        position: relative;
      }
      
      .prot {}
    </style>

</head>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a complex situation where the `float` property is creating the issue. Basically the yellow "image" is wrapping around the floated element and that's why it goes out of the black box and under the blue one (the float element). To avoid this you can use `absolute` instead of `float`.

```css
.container {
  width: 550px;
  height: 430px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}

.img_sx {
  width: 250px;
  height: 430px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img_dx {
  width: 210px;
  height: 390px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.quote {
  width: 230px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: coral;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.gif {
  width: 230px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.gif1 {
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 90px;
}

.gif2 {}

.burp {
  width: 230px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.prot {}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img_sx"></div>
  <div class="img_dx"></div>
  <div class="quote"></div>
  <div class="gif"><img class="gif1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Scandal_-_Yellow_album_cover.jpg"></div>
  <div class="burp"></div>
  <div class="prot"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to go:

```
.gif{
    position: relative;
}

.gif1{
    position:absolute;
 }
```

Hope it helps.